# Add Woocommerce Customers link to custom admin menu

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin, admin-menu

I'm creating a custom admin menu with my plugin and I want to add the Woocommerce Customers page as a submenu item. That was simple enough with `add_submenu_page`.
Now I'm trying to set my custom top menu to be active when the Customers page is loaded. I've been trying to do that by using the `parent_file` filter, but it doesn't seem to be working or I'm missing something.

```
function fix_admin_parent_file( $parent_file ) {
        
        if( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] === 'wc-admin' && 
            isset( $_GET['path'] ) && $_GET['path'] === '/customers'
          ) {
            
            $parent_file = 'custom_menu_slug';
            
        }
    
        return $parent_file;
    }
add_filter( 'parent_file', 'fix_admin_parent_file' );
```

Active menu is still the main Woocommerce menu and my menu remains "closed".

I also tried manipulating the `global $parent_file;` later using `admin_head` action, but that didn't seem to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.